# using bits transfer for an asp.net site for file transfer.

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, bit, microsoft-bits

I have a requirement to transfer files to server and retrive them back via an ASP.net site.
Heard using **BITS** is an approach.
Can I use BITS in a non windows client environment?
It would be nice if I can find a tutorial as well.

Comment: What did you try? We need more detail than this!

Comment: My question is Can I use BITS in a non windows client environment for file transfer?
I just need to clarify this.
So far I have refered (https://www.simple-talk.com/content/article.aspx?article=271)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope these links will be useful

[ASP.NET Uploading files in the background (BITS/AJAX?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555292/asp-net-uploading-files-in-the-background-bits-ajax)

[is there a BITS equivalent for Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24451/transfer-large-files-without-hogging-the-bandwidth-is-there-a-bits-equivalent-f) Hope you are referring Linux/Unix enviornments

Answer (score 1):

MSDN documents the [BITS Upload protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa362828%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). As that page says,

> Use the upload protocol to replace the BITS client or server software
>   with your own implementation.